# How to compare Time.sql

Tags: java, time

I want to compare a `Time` instance in a class with the current system time.I am using `before` and `after` method, but its giving unexpected results.

```
Time currentSystemTime = new Time(new java.util.Date().getTime());
Time t = Time.valueOf("23:25:00");
System.out.println(currentSystemTime+"  currentTime");
System.out.println(t+"  hardcoded Time");
```

Output

```
21:24:48  currentTime
23:25:00  hardcoded Time
```

But now ,how to compare these both times.I am trying the following.It is not working.

```
if(currentSystemTime.before(t))
{
  System.out.println("Hello"); 
}
```

This hello should execute,but its not.Is there any way to compare time.

Answer (score 1):

It's because they're in different years,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time currentSystemTime = new Time(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        Time t = Time.valueOf("23:25:00");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        System.out.println(currentSystemTime + "  currentTime");
        System.out.println(t + "  hardcoded Time");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(currentSystemTime));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(t));
        if (currentSystemTime.before(t)) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
```

Results in...

```
17:04:13  currentTime
23:25:00  hardcoded Time
2013-10-15T17:04:13.758+0100
1970-01-01T23:25:00.000+0100
```

The reason getTime() would work as @barwinkk has mentioned is it returns the long representation of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Comment: Better is time.getTime()

Comment: I'm proving the point as to why OP thinks he's getting the wrong result.

Comment: Your argument about the year is invalid -- `Time` object allows you to compare time ignoring date portion of a `Date`.

Comment: @barwnikk I think you miss the point of what david is demonstrating

Answer (score -1):

You can get time in milliseconds by calling getTime().
Now compare one with another and in this way you can get before or after.

Answer (score -1):

```
Time currentSystemTime = new Time(new java.util.Date().getTime());
Time t = Time.valueOf("23:25:00");
System.out.println(currentSystemTime+"  currentTime");
System.out.println(t+"  hardcoded Time");
if(currentSystemTime.getTime()<t.getTime())
{
  System.out.println("Hello"); 
}
```